# Which countries have won the fewest medals at the Olympics?

Tags: trivia, records, olympics

I am curious about the countries that have won the fewest medals at the Olympics - or are there countries that never won any kind of medal at the Olympics?

To keep the list a sensible size, let's ignore countries with populations below 5 million like Monaco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for countries that:

- have never won a Summer or Winter Olympic medal
- have a population of at least 5 million

As of the end of the 2020 Summer Olympics, there are **24** such countries in existence, and for the sake of completion, here they all are:

| Country | Population<sup>1</sup> | Summer Olympics | Winter Olympics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angola | 25 million | 10 | 0 |
| Bangladesh | 161 million | 10 | 0 |
| Benin | 11.5 million | 12 | 0 |
| Bolivia | 11.4 million | 15 | 6 |
| Cambodia | 15.3 million | 10 | 0 |
| Chad | 13.7 million | 13 | 0 |
| Democratic Republic of the Congo | 91.9 million | 11 | 0 |
| El Salvador | 6.4 million | 12 | 0 |
| Guinea | 12.4 million | 12 | 0 |
| Honduras | 9.6 million | 12 | 1 |
| Laos | 7.1 million | 10 | 0 |
| Libya | ~7 million | 12 | 0 |
| Madagascar | 26.3 million | 13 | 2 |
| Malawi | 18.1 million | 11 | 0 |
| Mali | 19.3 million | 14 | 0 |
| Myanmar | 53.6 million | 18 | 0 |
| Nicaragua | 6.2 million | 13 | 0 |
| Papua New Guinea | 8.6 million | 11 | 0 |
| Republic of the Congo | 5.2 million | 13 | 0 |
| Rwanda<sup>2</sup> | 11.3 million | 10 | 0 |
| Sierra Leone | 7.1 million | 12 | 0 |
| Somalia | 11 million | 10 | 0 |
| South Sudan | 11 million | 2 | 0 |
| Yemen | 28.5 million | 8 | 0 |

<sup>1</sup>As of December 2019
<sup>2</sup>Rwanda have won a Paralympic medal

A few points that stand out:

- Bolivia has appeared at the most Olympics (21) and the most Winter Olympics (6) of any country on the list.
- Myanmar has appeared at the most Summer Olympics (18) of any country on the list.
- Bangladesh has the highest population of any country on the list.

Comment: This summer, Burkina Faso, Turkmenistan and San Marino all won their first medals ever. Of course, San Marino doesn't qualify due to their population (~34000). Don't know about the other pop's.

Comment: Burkina Faso and Turkmenistan did qualify, and were in the earlier version of the table, but were removed when I updated it following Tokyo 2020.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table#List_of_NOCs_without_medals) - as of the 2018 Winter Olympics in Pyeongchang, South Korea, there are 71 (of 201) countries, that are/were part of the Olympic movement, that are yet to achieve a medal at any Olympic Games; Summer or Winter.

The worst performing country (with over 5m population) appears to be [Bolivia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolivia).

Bolivia have competed at 20 Olympic Games (14 Summer, 6 Winter), have sent 78 competitors ([63 Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summer_Olympics_competitors_for_Bolivia), [15 Winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Winter_Olympics_competitors_for_Bolivia)), but are yet to register a medal position.